# How to combine copy and singular properties in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

How can I create an array in my Azure ARM template, consisting of both singular objects and dynamically created objects using the copy mechanism.

In my ARM template I want to create a list that is combined of 'static' elements and ones that are dynamically created based on values in an array.

For instance I have the following resource:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",
     ...
    "properties": {
         ...
         // Option 1: I can do a singular accessPolicty
         "accessPolicies": [
                {
                    //  here I reference a static object
                      "objectId": "[parameters('configuredResourceId')]",
                    ...
                }
         ],
         // Option 2: Or iterate a list
         "copy": [
           {  
            // List of all properties per project. This will dynamically set the event processor (including secrets) and event hub.
            "name": "accessPolicies",
            "count": "[length(parameters('serviceNames'))]",
            "input": {
                "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('serviceNames')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')]), '2019-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                "permissions": {
                    "keys": "[parameters('keysAppPermissions')]",
                    "secrets": "[parameters('secretsAppPermissions')]"
                }
            }
        ]
     }
 }
```

When I only include option 1 or option 2 it works. However inclduing both (not ertirely unexpected) this gives the error that I can't define the same property twice:

```
 'Can not add property accessPolicies to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.'.
```

In some cases I can probably work around this, by using the copy in the variables and then adding elements to an array. But that doesn't work when I want to use different types of functions based on the resource state (such as fethcing Ids).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when adding Key-Vault Policies with the 'copy' method and also adding static Key-Vault Policies.

I solved it by adding the static policies as you described in the ARM. Next I defined another/child resource which is called: Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies

The last step I had to do was adding the dependsOn property and refer to the belonging Key-Vault.

The show you in JSON close to your code:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",
     ...
    "properties": {
         ...
         // Step 1: add static policies:
        "accessPolicies": [
            {
                //  here I reference a static object
                "objectId": "[parameters('configuredResourceId')]",
                ...
            }
        ],

    }
},
...
{
    "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    // Step 2: add depending key-vault (parent resource)
    "dependsOn": [ 
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        // Step 3: add the copy method to iterate policies
        "copy": [
            {
                // List of all properties per project. This will dynamically set the event processor (including secrets) and event hub.
                "name": "accessPolicies",
                "count": "[length(parameters('serviceNames'))]",
                "input": {
                    "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('serviceNames')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')]), '2019-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                    "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": "[parameters('keysAppPermissions')]",
                        "secrets": "[parameters('secretsAppPermissions')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }  
},
...
```

Please try the above ARM flow.

Comment: You're a lifesaver :D Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, add the objects in multiple variables (using the [copy function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-variables) as necessary) and use the [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#union) array function on the resource property.

Comment: Can you share an example? Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, I think the simplest is to:

1. create the vault with the static accessPolicies
2. for the dynamic list, use a child resource loop

A few links:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.keyvault/keyvault-add-access-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/accesspolicies?tabs=json